# If every ascending chain of primary ideals in $R$ stabilizes, is $R$ a Noetherian ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

A commutative ring $R$ is called Noetherian if every ascending chain of ideals in $R$ stabilizes, that is,
$$
I_1\subseteq I_2\subseteq I_3\subseteq\cdots
$$
implies the existence of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $I_n=I_{n+1}=I_{n+2}=\cdots$.

My question is the following:

> Does there exist a non-Noetherian ring $R$ such that every ascending chain of *primary* ideals stabilizes?

**Remark.** Note that there exists non-Noetherian ring $R$ such that every ascending chain of *prime* ideals stabilizes. This happens exactly when $R$ is non-Noetherian and $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is Noetherian topological space. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7392/a-non-noetherian-ring-with-textspecr-noetherian) and Exercise 12 of Chapter 6 in *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by Atiyah & Macdonald.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there do exist rings which aren't Noetherian but which do have ACC on primary ideals. An example is $\prod_{i\in\Bbb N} F_i$ where the $F_i$ are fields.

This is clearly not Noetherian, and because it is commutative and von Neumann regular, [all of its primary ideals are maximal](http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=2024).

This is even more dramatic than the ACC really, since you cannot even have a chain of two primary ideals :)

Comment: Excellent! So $\prod_{i\in\Bbb N} F_i$ is not Noetherian because we have the chain of ideals
$$(1, 0, 0, 0, ...)\subseteq (1, 1, 0, 0, ...)\subseteq (1,1,1,0,...)\subseteq\cdots$$
that does not terminate, right? And also, can we always conclude that direct product of von Neumann regular rings is always von Neumann regular? Thanks :)

Comment: @Prism Yes on both counts. Just think: if all the $F_i$ were VNR, then for each list of $a_i\in F_i$, you can find $x_i$ such that $a_ix_ia_i=a_i$. Then (the obvious product) $axa=a$ for that list $a$ in the product, too.

Comment: Great! Yes, it would be the component-wise product.

Answer (score 8):

In Commutative Algebra a suitable construction for counterexamples is given by the [*idealization*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207406/irreducible-components-of-the-prime-spectrum-of-a-quotient-ring-and-primary-deco/207468#207468) of an $A$-module $M$, sometimes denoted by $I_A(M)$. If one considers $R=I_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Q)$, then $R$ is not noetherian (since $\mathbb Q$ is not finitely generated as $\mathbb Z$-module) and it satisfies ACC on primary ideals (since these are of the following form: $p^n\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Q$ with $p$ prime and $n\ge 1$, $\{0\}\times\mathbb Q$ or $\{0\}\times\{0\}$).

Comment: Very interesting. I don't know anything about idealization yet, so I will make sure to study the link you mention :)

Comment: @Prism There is a little cluster of constructions like this that come in handy for making ideals out of modules. The "split null" extension of two rings $R,S$ and an $R,S$ bimodule $M$ is the set of matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}r&m\\0&s\end{bmatrix}$ for $r\in R, s\in S, m\in M$. In the link, the "trivial extension" that YACP refers to is a subring of the case when $S=R$ of constant diagonal matrices. A third construction uses a ring $R$ and a rng $M$ and defines $(r,m)+(r',m')=(r+r',m+m')$ and $(r,m)(r',m')=(rr',rm'+r'm+mm')$. In case $M^2=0$, you again get the "trivial extension".

Comment: @prism The third construction is usually called the Dorroh extension.

Comment: @rschwieb: Thanks for complementing the answer. Oh boy, more cool stuff to learn :)