# $\text{Spec}(A)$ Noetherian implies $A$ Noetherian?

Tags: commutative-algebra

This's about of exercise 6.8 in Atiyah. I think not: to take $A=k[x_1, \cdots, x_n, \cdots ]$ but I had have some problems for proof that $\text{Spec}(A)$ is Noetherian.

Comment: A polynomial ring with infinitely many variables (like your $A$) isn't noetherian. So it's not surprising you're having trouble showing that $Spec(A)$ is noetherian.

Comment: You're right. I want to show a counterexample.

Comment: @Tom Ryddle- there can be a non-Noetherian ring  $A$ such that $ \text{Spec}(A)$ is Noetherian. See this one-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7392/a-non-noetherian-ring-with-noetherian-spectrum?rq=1

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the purpose of your post then.